# How to remove spaces from list of integers?

Tags: python, list

My question seems to be very simple, but I still don't find the right answer for me. Maybe, if I am writing the specific explanation somebody can help me out.

So following case:

I have this list `a` (if I do `print(type(a)`) it will also return "class list"), which I have manually inserted into the script. Unfortunately if I do this programmatically it will always return list `b` in the example, which then isn't recognized correctly by the following program.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

My question is: How do I remove the spaces in list `b` to be like list `a`?

Comment: There are no spaces in the list, those two lists are equal. What *exactly* makes you think there's anything wrong with list `b`? What *exactly* does "isn't recognized correctly by the following program" mean?

Comment: It is very important to understand, there **are no spaces in the list**

Answer (score 0):

If the lazy automatic formatting doesn't suit your needs, then do it yourself:

```
print( '[' + (','.join(str(i) for i in b)) + ']' )
```

Comment: Not bad +1 but maybe include `print(str(b).replace(' ', ''))`.

Comment: This isn't removing spaces from a list, it instead produces/prints a string without ever putting spaces into it.

Comment: He doesn't have spaces in his list.  It's all numbers.  He has spaced in his printed REPRESENTATION of his list, because he's using the automatic formatting.  I've pointed out how to print it the way he wants.

Comment: They said nothing about printing the list.

Comment: But you and I both know that's the ONLY way you would get spaces in list of all numbers.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not convinced that that's actually their problem (or that there even really is a problem at all). It would be pretty unusual for something to work fine with `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` but not work with `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert list to a string and then use the replace function to replace all ', ' to ','.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
new_list = str(a)
print(new_list.replace(", ", ","))
```